# Error accessibility: role alert or aria-live polite?

Tags: html, accessibility

I was checking resources about what to use to make the errors in my **form** accessible and I found two possible approaches.
Considering we are compiling a form, which approach is the correct one?

1. To use `role="alert"` which implies `aria-live="assertive"`.
   This will disrupt the flow of the user and the error will be
   announce

```html
    <form>
      <label for="user-email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="user-email" aria-describedby="email-error">
      <span id="email-error" role="alert">Error message</span>
    </form>
```

2. Use only `aria-live="polite"` and make the assistive technology report the error after the user flow ended, without interrupting it immediately.

```html
   <form>
     <label for="user-email">Email:</label>
     <input type="email" id="user-email" aria-describedby="email-error">
     <span id="email-error" aria-live="polite">Error message</span>
   </form>
```